# mysqli - how do I count the number of rows before an insert without PHP?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

This is mostly an academic problem as I try to learn SQL better. Is there a way to do this in a single SQL statement, without first doing a row count, then another statement to insert?

Traditionally I'll do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable;
```

Then in PHP's result object I'll know the number of rows. let's say I call it `$totalrows`. Then I'll do

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`rows`) VALUES ($totalrows);
```

This of course requires separate queries and PHP.

I wonder if there is a way to accomplish the same using a single SQL statement? I'm using mysqli.

Comment: is it the same table or a separate one?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, look at the code. it's obviously the same table.

Comment: **By no means it is obvious**, as ones who ask has a fancy of changing random parts of their code when posting it on SO.

Comment: Anyway, with same table it makes even less sense.

Comment: I didn't change anything. You're just cranky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`rows`) 
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM mytable;
```

Comment: I don't know, but the question was if it was possible to do so, isn't it? I don't mind if it is useful for anything

Comment: @YourCommonSense , excuseme, but I can't understand why did you downvoted me... I think the answer is right....

Comment: @oscar, I upvoted you because I agree that people on SO spend too much effort on downvoting stuff that is academic

Comment: thanks @oscar. That's exactly what I needed and it works. @ yourCommonSense is of course downvoting the question because he's apparently unable to recognize the purpose of SO being about learning and sharing knowledge instead of trolling people with unconstructive comments